# Is the Gideon Sundback zipper doodle[Google,24th April] completely javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, google-doodle

Is the Gideon Sundback google doodle implemented in javascript ?

I tried to trace through firebug, but could not really "get" its implementation details ?

Any thoughts on how it might be implemented ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes it's JavaScript.

It uses the [`<canvas>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) element.

Here is the code:

```
(function () {
    var c = !0,
        d = !1;
    try {
        window.google || (window.google = {});
        google.doodle || (google.doodle = {});
        var f = google.doodle,
            h, j, k, l, m, n, o = 0,
            p = 23,
            q, r, s, u, v, w, x, y = 142,
            z = 356,
            A = 311,
            B = 0,
            C = 0,
            D = 30,
            E = 15,
            F = d,
            G, H = d,
            I = d,
            J = {
                back: {
                    src: "/logos/2012/sundback12-hp-s.png",
                    height: 31,
                    width: 24,
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                },
                s: {
                    src: "/logos/2012/sundback12-hp-l.jpg",
                    height: 120,
                    width: 186,
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                },
                F: {
                    src: "/logos/2012/sundback12-hp-l.jpg",
                    height: 120,
                    width: 186,
                    x: 186,
                    y: 0
                },
                i: {
                    src: "/logos/2012/sundback12-hp-s.png",
                    height: 60,
                    width: 28,
                    x: 24,
                    y: 0
                },
                top: {
                    src: "/logos/2012/sundback12-hp-s.png",
                    height: 23,
                    width: 8,
                    x: 52,
                    y: 0
                },
                G: {
                    src: "/logos/2012/sundback12-hp-s.png",
                    height: 7,
                    width: 15,
                    x: 60,
                    y: 0
                },
                B: {
                    src: "/logos/2012/sundback12-hp-s.png",
                    height: 7,
                    width: 15,
                    x: 75,
                    y: 0
                }
            },
            K = function () {
                google.psy && google.nav && google.nav.go ? google.nav.go("/search?q=Gideon+Sundback&ct=sundback12-hp&oi=ddle") : window.location.href = "/search?q=Gideon+Sundback&ct=sundback12-hp&oi=ddle"
            },
            L = function (a, b, g, i, e) {
                a.beginPath();
                a.moveTo(b, g);
                a.lineTo(i, e);
                a.stroke()
            },
            M = function (a, b, g) {
                var i = document.createElement("canvas"),
                    e = i.getContext("2d"),
                    t = j.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, g);
                t.addColorStop(0, "#f5f5f5");
                t.addColorStop(1, "#f1f1f1");
                e.fillStyle = t;
                e.fillRect(1, 1, b - 2, g - 2);
                e.lineWidth = 1;
                e.strokeStyle = "#d0d0d0";
                L(e, 1, 0, b - 1, 0);
                L(e, b, 1, b, g - 1);
                L(e, b - 1, g, 1, g);
                L(e, 0, g - 1, 0, 1);
                e.fillStyle = "#444";
                e.textAlign = "center";
                e.font = "bold 11px Arial,sans-serif";
                e.fillText(a, b / 2, g * 2 / 3);
                return i
            },
            N = function (a, b) {
                var g = document.createElement("canvas"),
                    i = g.getContext("2d");
                i.fillStyle = "#fff";
                i.fillRect(0, 0, b, 29);
                i.lineWidth = 1;
                i.strokeStyle = "#c0c0c0";
                L(i, 0, 0, b, 0);
                i.strokeStyle = "#d9d9d9";
                L(i, 0, 29, b, 29);
                var e = a ? 0 : b;
                L(i, e, 0, e, 29);
                return g
            },
            O = "move,-ie-grabbing,-moz-grabbing,-o-grabbing,-webkit-grabbing,grabbing".split(","),
            aa = "move,-ie-grab,-moz-grab,-o-grab,-webkit-grab,grab".split(","),
            P = function (a, b) {
                if (a) for (var g in b) a.style.cursor = b[g]
            },
            ba = function (a) {
                if (!H && !Q()) {
                    F = H = c;
                    google.listen(window, "mouseup", R);
                    google.listen(window, "mousemove", S);
                    h.style.zIndex = "2000";
                    P(h, O);
                    k && P(k, O);
                    l.q.blur();
                    google.psy && K();
                    T();
                    S(a)
                }
            },
            R = function () {
                if (!I && H) {
                    I = c;
                    F = d;
                    h.style.cursor = "auto";
                    if (k) k.style.cursor = "auto";
                    ca()
                }
            },
            S = function (a) {
                if (F) {
                    a ? a.stopPropagation && a.stopPropagation() : window.event.cancelBubble = c;
                    a.preventDefault ? a.preventDefault() : a.returnValue = d;
                    a = a || window.event;
                    G = !a ? [0, 0] : [(a.clientX || a.targetTouches && a.targetTouches[0] && a.targetTouches[0].clientX || 0) + (document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft || 0), (a.clientY || a.targetTouches && a.targetTouches[0] && a.targetTouches[0].clientY || 0) + (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0)];
                    a = B;
                    B = Math.max(0, G[1] - o - 30 - J.i.height);
                    if (f.z > 0) {
                        f.z--;
                        var b = B - a;
                        Math.abs(b) > 50 && (B = a + b * 0.25)
                    }
                    U()
                }
            },
            T = function () {
                var a = document.getElementById("mgmhppd");
                o = a ? a.offsetHeight : 0;
                a = o + 30;
                h.style.top = a + "px";
                var b = document.getElementById("ftby");
                if (b && b.parentNode) p = b.parentNode.offsetHeight;
                h.height = x = document.body.clientHeight - (o + (H ? 0 : 30 + p));
                var b = 833,
                    g = document.getElementById("gbqf");
                g && (b = Math.max(b, g.offsetWidth));
                h.width = v = Math.max(b, document.body.clientWidth);
                w = v / 2;
                G || (G = [0, 0]);
                G[0] = w;
                if (k) {
                    b = k.style;
                    b.top = h.style.top;
                    b.left = w - 236 + "px";
                    if (l) b.height = google.style.getPageOffsetTop(l) - a + "px"
                }
                da();
                U()
            },
            V = function (a) {
                a.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255,255,255,0)");
                a.addColorStop(0.01, "#eee");
                a.addColorStop(0.55, "#fff");
                a.addColorStop(0.58, "#b1b1b1");
                a.addColorStop(0.68, "#dedede");
                a.addColorStop(0.98, "#dedede");
                a.addColorStop(0.99, "rgba(255,255,255,0)")
            },
            da = function () {
                q = w - C + 1;
                r = w + C;
                s = q - 42;
                u = r + 42
            },
            U = function () {
                if (j) {
                    j.clearRect(0, 0, v, x);
                    var a = s - B,
                        b = u + B;
                    j.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    f.g || j.fillRect(0, 0, v, x);
                    j.beginPath();
                    j.moveTo(0, 0);
                    j.lineTo(a, 0);
                    j.arc(a, B, B + 21, -Math.PI / 2, 0, d);
                    j.lineTo(s, x);
                    j.lineTo(0, x);
                    j.lineTo(0, 0);
                    j.fill();
                    j.beginPath();
                    j.moveTo(v, 0);
                    j.lineTo(b, 0);
                    j.arc(b, B, B + 21, -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, c);
                    j.lineTo(u, x);
                    j.lineTo(v, x);
                    j.lineTo(v, 0);
                    j.fill();
                    W(J.s, -42, y, c);
                    W(J.F, -42, y, d);
                    if (H) {
                        W(J.v, 0, A, c);
                        W(J.w, 0, A, d)
                    }
                    if (H) {
                        var g = !l || l.q.dir != "rtl";
                        W(J.search, -57, z, g);
                        W(J.C, -57, z, !g)
                    }
                    g = j.createRadialGradient(a, B, B, a, B, B + 42);
                    V(g);
                    j.fillStyle = g;
                    j.fillRect(a, 0, B + 42, B);
                    a = j.createRadialGradient(b, B, B, b, B, B + 42);
                    V(a);
                    j.fillStyle = a;
                    j.fillRect(r, 0, B + 42, B);
                    a = j.createLinearGradient(s, 0, q, 0);
                    V(a);
                    j.fillStyle = a;
                    j.fillRect(s, B, 42, x - B);
                    a = j.createLinearGradient(u, 0, r, 0);
                    V(a);
                    j.fillStyle = a;
                    j.fillRect(r, B, 42, x - B);
                    a = J.B.height + 5;
                    for (b = 0; b < x; b = b + a) {
                        W(J.G, 3, b + a / 2, c);
                        W(J.B, 3, b, d)
                    }
                    a = A - 50;
                    a = Math.min(1, (a - (B - 50)) / a);
                    if (H && a > 0) {
                        j.save();
                        j.globalAlpha = a;
                        W(J.v, 0, A, c);
                        W(J.w, 0, A, d);
                        j.restore()
                    }
                    X(J.back, r - J.back.width / 2, B);
                    j.save();
                    a = 0;
                    G && (a = Math.atan((w - G[0]) / J.i.height));
                    j.translate(r + a * 6, B + 12 + Math.abs(a) * 6);
                    j.rotate(a);
                    X(J.i, 0 - J.i.width / 2, 0);
                    j.restore();
                    X(J.top, r - J.top.width / 2, B + 5)
                }
            },
            X = function (a, b, g) {
                b > h.width || g > h.height || j.drawImage(a.a, a.x, a.y, a.width, a.height, b, g, a.width, a.height)
            },
            W = function (a, b, g, i) {
                var e = i ? q : r;
                if (g > B) {
                    e = i ? e + b - a.width : e - b;
                    X(a, e, g)
                } else {
                    var t = 0;
                    B != 0 && (t = (B - g) / B);
                    b = B + 42 + b;
                    if (i) {
                        b = b - a.width;
                        e = e - 42 - B + Math.cos(t) * b
                    } else e = e + 42 + B - Math.cos(t) * b;
                    j.save();
                    j.translate(e, B - Math.sin(t) * b);
                    j.rotate(Math.PI * 2 + (i ? -t : t));
                    X(a, 0, 0);
                    j.restore()
                }
            },
            ea = function () {
                google.psy || Y()
            },
            Z = function (a) {
                var b = document.getElementById("hplogo-i");
                if (b) b.style.display = a ? "" : "none"
            },
            Y = function (a) {
                window.clearTimeout(f.A);
                if (n && m) n.style.position = m.style.position = "";
                if (h && (!a || !google.psy && google.browser.product.FIREFOX)) h.style.display = "none";
                if (k) k.style.display = "none";
                Z(c);
                google.unlisten(window, "resize", T);
                google.unlisten(window, "mouseup", R);
                google.unlisten(window, "mousemove", S)
            },
            fa = function () {
                if (google.msg) {
                    f.o && google.msg.unlisten(40, f.o);
                    f.o = function () {
                        H || Y();
                        f.g = c;
                        google.msg.unlisten(40, f.o);
                        f.p ? Y() : U();
                        return c
                    };
                    google.msg.listen(40, f.o);
                    f.k && google.msg.unlisten(64, f.k);
                    f.k = function () {
                        T();
                        google.msg.unlisten(64, f.k);
                        return c
                    };
                    google.msg.listen(64, f.k);
                    f.n && google.msg.unlisten(67, f.n);
                    f.n = function () {
                        H || Y();
                        google.msg.unlisten(67, f.n);
                        return c
                    };
                    google.msg.listen(67, f.n)
                }
            },
            Q = function () {
                var a = window.location.href;
                return a.indexOf("#") > -1 && /[^a-z]q=/.test(a) ? c : d
            },
            $ = function () {
                if (!f.D && google.dstr && google.rein) {
                    f.D = c;
                    google.dstr.push(ea);
                    google.rein.push($)
                }
                f.cpDestroy = Y;
                f.cpInit = $;
                a: {
                    for (var a = document.forms, b = ["f", "gs", "tsf", "gbqf"], g = 0, i; i = b[g++];) if (i = a[i]) {
                        l = i;
                        break a
                    }
                    l = null
                }
                m = l.btnK;
                n = l.btnI;
                if (!(a = !l)) if (!(a = !l.q)) if (!(a = l.q.value.length > 0)) if (!(a = Q())) {
                    h = document.getElementById("hplogo-z");
                    if (!h) {
                        h = document.createElement("canvas");
                        document.body.appendChild(h)
                    }
                    if (h.getContext) {
                        j = h.getContext("2d");
                        Z(d);
                        h.id = "hplogo-z";
                        a = h.style;
                        a.left = "0";
                        a.position = "absolute";
                        a.display = "";
                        a.visibility = "";
                        a.zIndex = "-1";
                        if (k = document.getElementById("hplogo-c")) {
                            k.onmouseover = U;
                            k.onmousedown = ba;
                            k.ontouchstart = ba;
                            k.style.display = "";
                            P(k, aa)
                        }
                        a = c
                    } else a = d;
                    a = !a
                }
                if (a) Z(c);
                else {
                    window.clearTimeout(f.A);
                    C = B = 0;
                    E = 15;
                    D = 30;
                    I = H = d;
                    f.g = d;
                    f.p = d;
                    f.z = 5;
                    f.g = d;
                    fa();
                    for (var e in J) {
                        a = J[e];
                        if (a.src) {
                            a.a = new Image;
                            a.a.onload = U;
                            a.a.src = a.src
                        }
                    }
                    if (l && n && m) {
                        J.search = {
                            a: M(m.innerText || m.textContent || m.value, m.offsetWidth, m.offsetHeight),
                            height: m.offsetHeight,
                            width: m.offsetWidth,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        };
                        J.C = {
                            a: M(n.innerText || n.textContent || n.value, n.offsetWidth, n.offsetHeight),
                            height: n.offsetHeight,
                            width: n.offsetWidth,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        };
                        e = Math.floor(google.style.getWidth(l.q) / 2);
                        J.v = {
                            a: N(c, e),
                            height: 29,
                            width: e,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        };
                        J.w = {
                            a: N(d, e),
                            height: 29,
                            width: e,
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        }
                    }
                    google.listen(window, "resize", T);
                    T();
                    y = Math.max(0, google.style.getPageOffsetTop(l) - o - 15 - J.s.height - 30);
                    z = google.style.getPageOffsetTop(m) - o - 30;
                    A = google.style.getPageOffsetTop(l) - o - 30;
                    if (l && n && m) {
                        b = google.style.getWidth(n) - google.style.getWidth(m);
                        a = e = 42;
                        b > 0 ? e = e + b : a = a - b;
                        b = l.q.dir != "rtl";
                        n.style.position = m.style.position = "relative";
                        n.style[b ? "left" : "right"] = e + "px";
                        m.style[b ? "right" : "left"] = a + "px"
                    }
                    U()
                }
            },
            ca = function () {
                B = B + D;
                D = D + 2;
                G[0] = G[0] + (w - G[0]) * 0.3;
                if (B > x) {
                    C = C + E;
                    E = E + 5;
                    da()
                }
                U();
                if (C < w) f.A = window.setTimeout(ca, 30);
                else {
                    G[0] = w;
                    f.p = c;
                    if (google.psy && f.g) Y();
                    else {
                        Y(c);
                        K()
                    }
                }
            };
        google.x ? google.x({
            id: "DOODLE"
        }, $) : $()
    } catch (ga) {
        google.ml(ga, d, {
            cause: "DOODLE"
        })
    };
})();
```